# Accessing returned data from FB.api()

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am creating a Facebook app using JavaScript. I wish to access a users Facebook Photos using the Facebook Graph API. I have done this, but now I would like to access the elements returned and filter out certain items, i.e. If the name of a photo contained a certain word, or a certain person is tagged in a photo, I want to output this element.

However, I am struggling to access the data. I have tried using a for loop to iterate through the array returned, as shown below.

```
function check(){
 FB.api(
  '/me',
  'GET',
  {"fields":"photos.limit(100){name,album,created_time,place}"},
  function(response) {
      console.log(response);
      for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length ; i++) {
       //do checks here
      };
  }
);
```

I believe I am going wrong with 'response.data.length', however this is the way it is done in Facebook's provided examples.

I think you can use fql queries to access, however I understand that it is only in use until August 2016 so was looking for a better way of doing this.

Comment: did you debug response.data? what does your console output look like?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined - is what I get when I try running it. Just a bit unsure how else i would do it.

Comment: ok, and what do you get for the console.log(response) entry? please add the complete debug response.

Comment: - Object {photos: Object, id: "**"}


- id: "**"

- photos: Object

- data: Array[100]

- paging: Object

__proto__: Object

__proto__: Object

This is what I get - Sorry its hard to read - I dont really understand why I cant access the photos in the data array

Comment: use the chrome browser for debugging. the debugging tools are the best and you can view all objects.

Comment: anyway, i just figured it out. see my answer, i guess that´s the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function check(){
 FB.api(
  '/me',
  'GET',
  {"fields":"photos.limit(100){name,album,created_time,place}"},
  function(response) {
      console.log(response.photos.data);
      for (var i = 0; i < response.photos.data.length ; i++) {
       //do checks here
      };
  }
);
```

After all, you are accessing the photos as field, not as endpoint. The other code should work with this API call:

```
/me/photos?limit=100&fields=name,album,created_time,place
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much! Still trying to get my head around the Facebook SDK

Comment: you are welcome. please don´t forget to accept my answer ;)